# numpy row pair sum of squared row wise differences without for loops (only api calls)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

For those who can read Latex, this is what I am trying to compute:

$$k_{xyi} = \sum_{j}\left ( \left ( x_{i}-x_{j} \right )^{2}+\left ( y_{i}-y_{j} \right )^{2} \right )$$

where x and y are rows of a matrix A.

For computer language only folk this would translate as:
k(x,y,i) = sum_j( (xi - xj)^2 + (yi - yj)^2  )
where x and y are rows of a matrix A.

So k is a 3d matrix.

Can this be done with API calls only? (no for loops)

Here is testing startup:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(4,4)
k = np.empty((4,4,4))
for ix in range(4):
    for iy in range(4):
        x = A[ix,]
        y = A[iy,]
        sx = np.power(x - x[:,np.newaxis],2)
        sy = np.power(y - y[:,np.newaxis],2)
        k[ix,iy] = (sx + sy).sum(axis=1).T
```

And now for the master coders, please replace the two for loops with numpy API calls.

Update:
Forgot to mention that I need a method that saves up RAM space, my A matrices are usually 20-30 thousand squared. So it would be great if your answer does not create huge temporary multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 4):

I would change your latex to look something more like the following- it is much less confusing imo:

[image]

From this I assume the last line in your expression should really be:

```
k[ix,iy] = (sx + sy).sum(axis=-1)
```

If so, you can compute the above expression as follows:

```
Axij = (A[:, None, :] - A[..., None])**2
k = np.sum(Axij[:, None, :, :] + Axij, axis=-1)
```

The above first expands out a memory intensive 4D array. You can skip this if you are worried about memory by introducing a new for loop:

```
k = np.empty((4,4,4))
Axij = (A[:, None, :] - A[..., None])**2
for xi in range(A.shape[0]):
    k[xi] = np.sum(Axij[xi, None, :, :] + Axij, axis=-1)
```

This will be slower, but not by as much as you would think since you still do a lot of the operations in numpy. You could probably skip the 3D `Axij` intermediate, but again you are going to take a performance penalty doing so.

If your matrices are really 20k on an edge your 3D output will be 64TB. You are not going to do this in numpy or even in memory (unless you have a large scale distributed memory system).

Comment: Oh man, what you do is correct and cool and you have my upvote, but you create a lot of matrices over there and I need to save up some ram. My A matrix is "only" 20K^2. I will update my question with this extra bit, sorry. Brilliant solution btw!

Comment: I updated the question of a algorithm that does use a 4D intermediate; however, you are not going to have a 3D output 20k on an edge and store it in memory.

Comment: yea, well i was hoping to do the last dimension i in batches, ill check your update later, thanks!